# Mix-up of bool and Datatypes.bool after Require Import Omega

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

I'm going through software foundations and ran into an error.

> ERROR : The term "true" has type "bool" while it is expected to have type  "Datatypes.bool"

for the proof below.

```
Theorem beq_nat_true : forall n m,
  beq_nat n m = true -> n = m.
```

I found out that this is happening when I use `Require Import Omega`.
Any tips, suggestions or explanations of what `Omega` introduces into the environment?

Comment: Please show complete code to reproduce the problem. Also tell us which version of Coq you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Omega` module indirectly imports many definitions of the standard library that manipulate natural numbers, some of which end up shadowing parts of Software Foundations. The `beq_nat` function is one of them. The problem arises because the version of the standard library for `beq_nat` returns standard booleans, whereas the one of SF returns its redefined booleans.

We noticed this problem a while ago, and have already fixed it in the [current version](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis500/current/index.html). If you don't want to redownload everything (or if you have imported `Omega` yourself), you can also just qualify `beq_nat` to use the right version. My guess is that `Basics.beq_nat` should work.